# after last image slideshow doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

My slideshow works fine in the first time and show three images correctly but it doesn't show image2 again.I think there is a problem in my jquery code but I can't find it.If there is an easier way to create a slideshow like this please tell me.

```js
slideswitch();
var i=2;
function slideswitch()
{
 "use strict";
 i++;
 if(i===4){i=1;}
 if(i===1)
 {
 $('#img1').animate({right:'0'});
 $('#img3').animate({left:'-100%'}); 
 document.getElementById('img2').style.right='-100%';
 }
 else if(i===2)
 {
 $('#img2').animate({right:'0'});
 $('#img1').animate({left:'-100%'});
 document.getElementById('img3').style.right='-100%'; 
 }
 else if(i===3)
 {
 $('#img3').animate({right:'0'});
 $('#img2').animate({left:'-100%'});
 document.getElementById('img1').style.right='-100%'; 
 }
 setTimeout(slideswitch,3000);
}
```

```css
#img3
{
 position:absolute;
 right:-100%;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
#img2
{
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
#img1
{
 position:absolute;
 right:-100%;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
.show
{
 width:100%;
 height:500px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SlideShow</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="show" class="show">
<img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" id="img1"/>
<img src="http://wpguru.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CSS-Logo-214x300.png" id="img2" />
<img src="http://ric.mclaughlin.today/assets/themes/ricify/images/javascript.png" id="img3"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a value to left or right for any element you must make the other is auto :

I made some edits to your script you can see it here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/n6c7mstn/

```
slideswitch();
var i=2;
function slideswitch()
{
  "use strict";
  i++;
  if(i===4){i=1;}
  if(i===1)
  {
    $('#img1').animate({right:'0'});
    $('#img3').animate({left:'-100%'}); 
    document.getElementById('img2').style.right='-100%';
  }
  else if(i===2)
  {
    $('#img2').animate({right:'0'}).css('left','auto');
    $('#img1').animate({left:'-100%'}).css('right','auto');
    document.getElementById('img3').style.right='-100%';    
    document.getElementById('img3').style.left='auto';  
  }
  else if(i===3)
  {
    $('#img3').animate({right:'0'}).css('left','auto');
    $('#img2').animate({left:'-100%'}).css('right','auto');
    document.getElementById('img1').style.right='-100%';    
    document.getElementById('img1').style.left='auto';  
  }
  setTimeout(slideswitch,3000);
}
```